# Comparing resource and request resource in firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a simple firestore rule:

`allow update: if request.resource.data.reservedBy == resource.data.reservedBy;`

my payload in the simulator is

{"**name**":"/databases/(default)/documents/books/I3dbzzwGJGXnqMQBOxoP","data":{"reservedBy":"Ivanko"}}

and the method is "update". The value of the field 'reservedBy' is completely different in the actual record.

No matter what I do, no matter what i change the payload to, the rule will always return true and allow the update. Is that a bug or am i missing something. Interestingly, if I change "update" to "create", the rule works as expected. Anyone else encountered this?

Thanks.

Comment: The simulator has been known to have bugs.  Does this work with actual updates?

Comment: Ah interesting, haven't tested it. My frontend mirrors this rule so a bit tricky to check. I'll write a couple of manual tests and will report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just got an answer from the Firebase team saying that it is indeed a simulator bug, and that the rule should work in production.

Answer (score 2):

I have been dealing with a similar issue and I found this to be the culprit...excerpt from (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions). --For update operations that only modify a subset of the document fields, the request.resource variable will contain the "pending" document state "after" the operation.

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding what `pending document state` means. Does `request.resource.data` contains the entire updated document or just the subset of the document which is being updated?

Comment: I haven't dug into this since my original post but from my understanding the request.resource.data will contain the entirety of the document reflecting the state of the document if it was to be allowed. You could test this to see if only a subset is sent over though. I would think you could have a field called population and update it to zero before any rules are applied. Then add an update rule afterwards such as "if request.resource.data.population > 0". Then change a field other than the population field. If it disallows the update then you know the population field was sent.